# Yii Full month name in CGrivView

Tags: php, yii

i have smth like this

```
array(
'name'=>'date',
'type'=>'date',
'value'=>'date("M j, Y", $data->date)',
),
```

And it's showing a date in format like Year/Month/Day all in numbers, but i want a full name of month like : 10 September 2014. I searched internet, but nothing help me with this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    array(
        'name'=>'date',
        'type'=>'date',
        'value'=>'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(CDateTimeParser::parse($data->date, "yyyy-MM-dd"),"medium",null)'
    ),
```

**Edit:**

**Tested code:**
i have tested this code may be it will help you.

```
<?php
    $date=date('yyyy-MM-dd');
    $form=Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(CDateTimeParser::parse($date, "yyyy-MM-dd"),"medium",null);
    CVarDumper::Dump($form,100,true);
    die();
    ?>
```

It returns me

```
'Feb 1, 2014'
```

Comment: i try smth like this before but i get error : "Undefined variable: data"

Comment: @TomTom check edits and let me know. I have put commas in last line

Comment: well now i got error : "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'yyyy' (T_STRING), expecting ')'"

Comment: Use double ", not single ', before yyyy-MM-dd. The enclosing character of the string is ' so inside you need to use "

Comment: @TomTom you cant use single comma within single comma. I did not debug code so my typo.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot about that - sorry. But now date is like "2014/02/01" so not exctly what i need

Comment: what is your initial format of the date? i have tested above code and its working for me.

Comment: I'm very thankful Jailed for your help - but this date is from database(sqllite), this is now today date, and I need to transform that date from "24/02/2012" to "24 February 2012" form.

Comment: And i forgot to said that i save date as string..Sorry guys. Now i try to do smth with strtotime(); but still nothing..

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
'value'=>'date("j F Y",$data->date)'
```